# Is there a way to specify that an artist be drawn as a separate layer in an svg file in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg

I've been making plots using matplotlib and saving them as svg files. Sometimes I get overlapping artists (legend with line plot for example) and redoing the locations through the script is just too much of a hassle at times.

I've discovered that it is possible to open an SVG in Inkscape and to rearrange any artist inside my plot to my liking. However, there is one little annoyance that I'd like to take care of, if possible:

Before you can select an artist with the move tool in Inkscape and move it, you must first create a new layer and then move that artist to the new layer. The move-tool can only affect layers, it seems, so selecting and moving a single path that belongs to one artist is impossible.

As I said, I can just put an artist in a new layer manually, but I'd like to know if there is some way in matplotlib to specify that an artist is supposed to be created as a path/object in it's own layer so that I don't have to do that anymore once I open the SVG in Inkscape.

[image]

As I was writing this I've found a way to make artists movable without creating new layers first: Find the artist in the outliner on the right. Select it and cut it out with Ctrl+X, then immediately paste it back with Ctrl+V. Now you can move your selected artist. The question still stands though: Can matplotlib specify a SVG keyword so that an artist is written to it's own dedicated layer?

Comment: If you're in InkScape, why not just use `ctrl+shift+g` to ungroup everything? Keep hitting `ctrl+shift+g` to keep breaking the grouping down further, move what you want, then select it all and group it with `ctrl+g`. With Inkscape and SVG's from Matplotlib, you can break it all the way down to individual points/ticks/whatever on your graph.